# What's a suffix that means to find something cute or adorable?

Tags: single-word-requests, suffixes

"Xenophobia" is being fearful of outsiders, and "xenophilia" would be to love outsiders.

To fit in with these words, I'm looking for a suffix to attach to the "xeno~" prefix to in order to create a word that means to find a person to be adorable or cute because they are foreign.

"Xenophilia" does not fit, because the implication of the "~philia" suffix is too accepting and desirous of the target. To say someone was a xenophile is more or less to say they would love it all the more if they were surrounded by foreigners all the time.

I'm very much looking for something where the object of adoration is simultaneously considered diminutive and not necessarily respected. Like how people might consider a foreign person to be cute because of their accent and behaviour, but still have a sense that they are alien to the host culture. People may laugh along with a foreigner's antics without malice, but still regard that foreigner as necessarily separate.

Does such a suffix that means "cute" in the sense of "diminutive" exist?

Comment: You should looking for a prefix rather it seems: kind of cutie-ET, not ET-cutie.

Comment: I can't think of a latin or greek suffix, but -ling can be used to form a word that's likely to make the hearer think of something young, cute, and inferior.

Comment: @JasonM There are plenty of *-ling* like suffixes. However, they don't seem to gel with the context.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of diminutive suffixes, but none that mean *cute*, at least in English. They do impart a sense of affection, though.

- -**ie**(**s**) (hottie, sweetie, Petie, *cutie*, duckie, footsie, *elevensies*, onesies.
- -**y** (daddy, doggy, kitty, mommy)
- -**sy** (Flopsy, Mopsy)
- -**ling** (duckling, dear-ling)
- -(d)**oodle** (honeydoodle, canoodle)
- -**et**/-**ette**/-**etti**/-**etto**/-**it**/-**ita**/-**ito**/-**itta** (mamacita, amaretto, Manolito)
- -**let**/-**lette** (applet, chicklet, piglet)
- -**kin**(**s**) (catkin, lambkin, ?pumpkin, honeykins, Sallykins)

I think you're going to have to create something, and I'm afraid it might be rather silly in English.

*Xenodoodle* is, well, silly, but certainly connotes a feeling that you think the xeno- is cute.

*Xenokins?* *Xenolette?* *Xenoling?*

Comment: Thank you for this response. One thing I notice about all the listed suffixes here is that they describe the target, not the source. I need a word, or part of a word, that describes the source of the feelings. The suggested words built out of the prefix "~xeno" are interesting, but to be honest, they seem confused as to whether they point to sources or targets.

Comment: @DaveMG - can you give me an idea of what this word would look like? Hyphenating is fine. I don't quite get the distinction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but to clarify further on my comment, I mean that a suffix like "~ie", as in "cutie" describes the person who is thought of as being cute, not the person who thinks it. However, a "xenophile" describes the person who is the source of the feeling, the one who loves outsiders. Thus, similarily, I need a word that is like "xeno-adorer". Hmmm.. actually, now that I say it, "xeno-adorer" feels kind of close.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a word to designate a person who thinks foreigners are cute? OK, I think I see. No, I can't think of any such word. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> "Xenophilia" does not fit, because the implication of the "~philia" suffix is too accepting and desirous of the target. To say someone was a xenophile is more or less to say they would love it all the more if they were surrounded by foreigners all the time.

*Xenophilia* covers a wider range than you suggest here. What you are describing would certainly fall under *xenophilia*, but not all reasonable uses of *xenophilia* would match your target meaning.

As such, if I wanted to restrict myself to classical roots, I'd probably use *xenophile* to describe what you are talking about, but perhaps clarify further if necessary. (Not necessary in "Ever the xenophile, Alice kept describing Bob as 'a cutie' and his accent as 'adorable'" because the rest of the sentence makes it clear the level of attraction I'm describing, but perhaps necessary otherwise).

If I really wanted to express "cuteness" or "finding something cute", I probably wouldn't restrict myself to classical roots.

The language we choose to borrow from in a given case is based on:

1. The language itself (that is, the range of words and phrases it makes available).
2. The culture(s) associated with that language.
3. Our understanding of said culture(s). (That is, an inaccurate view of the culture would have as much, if not more, effect than the actual facts of the matter).

With this in mind, if I want to coin a phrase of "finding foreigners cute", the answer is obvious: Borrow from Japanese.

*Gaijin*, *外人*: Outsider, foreigner. (Pretty much as with the Greek *ξένος* you were originally using).
*Moe*, *萌え*: Slang, a reaction of attraction to "cute" characters, people or things, the target of such an attraction, something which produces a feeling of moe, often used as a suffix. It wouldn't really apply to the person feeling the moe, but phrases using it get shortened further when borrowed into English, so for the purposes here, it would.

Therefore, I'd use *gaijinmoe*, if I really didn't find *xenophile* or *xenophilia* to be specific enough.

Do note that not some things you can find googling for *外人萌え* are NSFW.

Comment: I had the same kind of answer... but I don't know how to make it apply to *someone else*. Does this transfer the moe to the person doing the moeing? I'm having a hard time even understanding how that can be done in one word. I do like your suggestion, though.

Comment: @medica while I understand that in Japanese the person doing the moeing would be a (in this example) a *gaijin moe otaku* or a *gaijin moe zoku* (c.f. *figure moe zoku/figyua moe zoku*), as borrowed into English via animé fans, manga fans and other Japanophiles and English-speaking otaku, I've heard *moe* used for those who *moe* too: Borrowing mutates, and while some such fans may have a passion for accuracy in these matters, many such words have slightly different meanings when borrowed into English than in the original Japanese. Really, it's only those borrowed meanings that I know...

Comment: @medica ...much about at all, and not that much (I certainly like manga, but I'm no hardcore otaku by any stretch). In particular many words with several meanings in Japanese have only one very specific meaning in English, that isn't even the most common meaning in Japanese much of the time. So, while I'm pretty sure it would be wrong in Japanese, it would be no less wrong borrowed as that, than many other such terms are.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think this is a great suggestion.

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion, but since the suggested Japanese term is a phrase that does not exist in Japanese as any kind of routine expression, why would one look to Japanese as a way to express this concept instead of, say, Arabic, Chinese, or Swahili? Since I can't say "In Japanese they had a word for this...", it seems odd and arbitrary to say "So, I made up a word in Japanese..."

Comment: If one of those languages has a strong value on cuteness in the associated popular culture and a productive suffix for cuteness that is also used in English, then they'd be good too.

Comment: 萌え is only used in English, if at all, among a very niche subculture. I live in Tokyo where the incidence of non-Japanese with a familiarity and integration with Japanese language is higher than anywhere else, including some people very enthusiastic about the anime and manga subculture, and absolutely no one uses 萌え as part of English. They use 元気, すみません, and other Japanese words mixed in their English, but never 萌え.

Comment: Hah! No, if you live in Tokyo then bastardised Japanese filtered solely through popular culture is not a good source. Actual good Japanese might be a reasonable source, or not, but I was thinking of the sort of people who are outside of Japan and Japanese culture who are manga enthusiasts (i.e. the sort of people for whom "otaku" doesn't have a negative connotation, though they may or may not be aware that it does in Japan) because I can't think of anyone else who'd want a word for finding something "cute". Otherwise I'd restrict my answer to the first two paragraphs.